# How do I assert final JSON that ends up in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

According to the [testing section of the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_testing), I can verify that a particular payload has been sent to a stream. If that's a POJO message that gets converted into JSON in the end though, I can't seem to find native support for asserting that JSON. Instead, I can only access the payload in the form of that POJO and do all sorts of assertions on it.

Currently, I just have a separate set of tests to ensure that a particular POJO type gets serialized into JSON in a way that I expect. But maybe there's a built-in support for testing the whole thing from calling a method to verifying the final JSON that ends up in Kafka.

Comment: I suggest you to take a look into existing tools for JSON assertion. Here you can find some discussion on the matter: https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/75

Comment: The question here is how to get to that very JSON in Spring Cloud Stream tests. Asserting its contents is the easy part.

Comment: Doesn't `MessageCollector` work for you? Take a look here as well, please: https://spring.io/blog/2017/10/24/how-to-test-spring-cloud-stream-applications-part-i

Comment: I send a POJO message like a User object. And that's what I get from the message collector — not the final JSON that ends up in Kafka after Jackson serializes it. So my question is how to get the final JSON to be able to do assertions on it directly.

Comment: Examples in that blog post are simplistic in the sense that they just work with strings.

Comment: Well, just perform JSON conversion. Why not? There is an integration testing sample: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/master/testing/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/testing/processor/integration/ToUpperCaseProcessorIntTests.java. Also the current Spring Cloud Stream 2.0 version does that JSON conversion on a bit higher level you indeed get conversion result from the `MessageCollector` now, before it is sent to the Bidner at all.

Comment: I thought about doing the conversion myself, but I wasn't sure it would be the same object mapper and that could give me falsely green tests. But I guess I'll have to do it. Good to know about 2.0; I'm still on 1.x though.

Comment: I think you can just inject `ObjectMapper` from the application context since it is the one Spring Cloud Stream uses. That one is auto-configured by Spring Boot anyway.

Comment: That's what I basically do right now, but in separate tests that only focus on POJO serialization. I can never be sure there's only one Object Mapper after dealing with weird Spring HATEOAS object mapper wizardry. But I guess it's fine when dealing with Spring Cloud Stream. Thanks.